# Google scripts create new page elements in gmail

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I apologize if this is naive, but I couldn't find a succinct answer.

Is it possible to make front end objects (buttons, etc.) appear in someone's gmail inbox using code from a Google script? Or does this require making a browser extension?

I've read the documentation and various tutorials for Google script, but it appears I can only do things like manage settings and send emails, not add entirely new page elements.

[Google app scripts overview](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview)

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand what you want, how about using Gmail Add-ons? https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/

Comment: Hi, this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you, my Google fu failed me here.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was solved.